# Storing a host URL to fetch a resource on an iOS device

Tags: ios, api, storage

Let's say I had an API that told me "for X resource, use this host". My iOS app would then store that host and use it whenever it needs to fetch resource X.

I'm wondering what security concerns there are around this? If I had to support this, would this make sense to store it somewhere encrypted (like the keychain) rather than user-defaults/sql?

I feel like worst-case, someone could redirect the app's traffic to their own thing. But I don't know if this is any more concerning than someone just modifying a hosts file, so maybe I'm worrying about nothing?

Thank you!

Comment: How would you connect to that host then? How would the client know where to connect?

Comment: @schroeder There would be a fixed URL to retrieve the host. But all other traffic would use a dynamic host